# How to Remove Articles Based on User

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2012, merge-replication

I am using merge replication on SQL 2012. I have a very large database with a large number of tables. The subscribers are using netbooks.

I have a filtering scheme that controls which tables end up being empty at the subscriber. We are saying this for instance 'the user bob is not interested in the street light table so he will receive that table, but with no data in it'. That filtering is working fine.

What I am interested in is whether you can go further and not even sent the streetlight table to that user. The reason I ask is running the scripts to create the tables and add the replication triggers is quite slow on the netbook when you are talking about a large number of tables.

Here is the breakdown of my sync to the netbook,

```
Download Snapshot Files     0:03:33.580
Applying Scripts            0:05:02.290
Bulk Copying                0:07:59.723
Applying Scripts            0:14:31.777
Finishing Sync              0:03:59.720
```

So it turns out that applying the scripts is a large portion of the sync.

Comment: I don't think it was meant to be used that way. You'd probably have to create a separate publication for each user.

Comment: Thanks. Or suck it up and accept that it may take a bit longer. With hundreds of users multiple publications won't work really.